# Why am I getting a NullPointerException when fetching JSON?

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I keep getting a NullPointerException at `return place`.
When I was debugging the app, the code skips the `onFailure()` and `onResponse()` methods.

Previously, this worked but I refactored it into the current classes.

```
class Repository private constructor() {

    private val baseUrl: String = "http://api.openweathermap.org/"

    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
            .build()

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build()

    val networkApi = retrofit.create(NetworkApi::class.java)


    private object Holder { val INSTANCE = Repository() }

    companion object {

        val instance: Repository by lazy { Holder.INSTANCE }

    }

    fun fetchWeatherData(placeName: String): Place {

        var place: Place? = null

        val call: Call<Place> = networkApi.getPlaceWeather(placeName)

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<Place> {

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Place>?, t: Throwable?) {
                println(t?.message)
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Place>?, response: Response<Place>?) {

                if (response != null && response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {

                    place = response.body() as Place

                    println(place.toString())
                }
            }
        })

        return place!!
    }
}


class MainPresenter(private val view: MainContract.View, val context: Context) : MainContract.Presenter {

    val repository = Repository.instance

    ...

    override fun updateListOfPlaces() {

        var places = mutableListOf<Place>()

        for (index in 0 until favPlaceStrings.size) {
            places.add(repository.fetchWeatherData(favPlaceStrings.elementAt(index)))
        }

        view.showFavouritePlaces(places)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to invert your logic. You cannot simply "return data" from a network call that you're waiting for

Instead, loop over the list, make requests, then show/update the view

```
for (index in 0 until favPlaceStrings.size) {
    val call: Call<Place> = networkApi.getPlaceWeather(favPlaceStrings.elementAt(index))
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<Place> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Place>?, t: Throwable?) {
            println(t?.message)
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Place>?, response: Response<Place>?) {

            if (response != null && response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {

                val place: Place = response.body() as Place
                places.add(place)  // move this list to a field 
                println(place.toString())
                view.showFavouritePlaces(places) // this is fine that it's inside a loop
            }
        }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you're using retrofit makes it have an asynchronous behaviour, meaning the code within `onFailure` and `onResponse` might run after or before you have a chance to return from `fetchWeatherData`. In other words, you cannot assume that `place` will have a value when you return from `fetchWeatherData` and this is actually what's happening, `place` is still `null` and calling `!!` will cause the null pointer exception you're having.

To fix this you either change the way you're using retrofit to be synchronous, or you use an approach like callbacks.

Personally, I prefer the callback approach / reactive streams and this you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44872115/how-can-i-return-value-from-onresponse-of-retrofit-v2).

Making the code synchronous will most likely lead to other issues such as network calls on the main thread, which are not allowed and crash the app.