# Get values with callback method for other class in android retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, asynccallback

I'm trying to get the data I parse from onResponse method via Callback. Here is my ApiClient:

```
public class ApiClient implements Callback<Map<String, Channel>> {


    private ChannelCallback listener;

    static final String BASE_URL = "https://www.radyoodtu.com.tr/";

    public void start(ChannelCallback listener) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

        RestInterface restInterface = retrofit.create(RestInterface.class);

        Call<Map<String, Channel>> call = restInterface.getChannels();
        call.enqueue(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<Map<String, Channel>> call, Response<Map<String, Channel>> response) {
        System.out.println(response.code());
        if(response.isSuccessful()) {
            Map<String, Channel> body = response.body();
            listener.setChannels(body);
            List<Channel> channels = new ArrayList<>(body.values());
            for (Channel channel : body.values()) {
                System.out.println(channel.getSong());
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<Map<String, Channel>> call, Throwable t) {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

and this is the class I'm trying to get the data:

```
public class Radio implements ChannelCallback {

    private ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();


    public Radio(){
        apiClient.start(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void setChannels(Map<String, Channel> body) {
        this.apiClient.onResponse(body); // NOT WORKING
    }
}
```

here is my Interface:

```
public interface ChannelCallback {

    void setChannels(Map<String, Channel> body);
}
```

what I need to do is get the onResponse body data for Radio class I'm using right now. In Radio class I have to create a List of channel objects with that data I need but I can't even get the data so I can't even create that list. I don't know how to manipulate the data from listener at all and I don't know how can I access that listener I use in ApiClient in Radio class.

Comment: [This post on 'How can I return value from onResponse of Retrofit v2'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44881355/5015207) may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got a cyclic reference here. Radio calls ApiClient start, which triggers the network request, which calls Radio.setChannels, which tries to call the client *again*.

I think you need to resolve two things:

1. Avoid this cyclic reference
2. You pass the `listener` to `ApiClient.start()` but you never assign it to the actual value inside `ApiClient`. So, my guess is that you get an NPE here if you have a successful response.

Answer (score 0):

```
//i think no need to impliments ChannelCallback if this code works
//just asign your interface and apiclient in class
public class Radio implements ChannelCallback {
private ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();
private ChannelCallback channelCallback;

and in inside radio()
public Radio(){
apiClient.start(this);
channelCallback = apiClient.onResponse(body).create(ChannelCallback.class);
channelCallback.setChannels(Map<String, Channel> body)
}

//and recieve callback 
}
```

Comment: So what happened to @Override setChannels? Also 'body' cannot resolve.