# How do I set a global value inside the onResponse() method of Retrofit and pass to an override function?

Tags: android, asynchronous, kotlin, interface, retrofit2

I am trying to get fetching a JSON object which is a list of travel_history. I properly managed to fetch all data.

My goal is to calculate the minimum distance using lat long points available in this travel_history list.
And I have achieved it too.

Now I want to pass this calculated min Distance lat long to onMapReady() function. I have tried all possible ways. I have search about this and found that I was calling calculateDistance() inside an asynchronous onResponse() method, so I created TravelHistoryInterface() and then called DistanceCalculator there but SAME RESULTS.

Please help me to pass destinationLat destinationLong in onMapReady() function

P.S.: Map is working fine. I have added all necessary methods. Every other supporting function like distanceCalculator() and all works perfectly fine.

```
class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), TravelHistoryInterface, OnMapReadyCallback {


private var mTravelLocations: MutableList<Travel_HistoryDTO> = ArrayList()
private var minDistance: Double = 1000000000.0
lateinit var strList1: List<String>
var mylat: Double = 0.0
var mylung: Double = 0.0
var destinationLat: Double = 0.0
var destinationLong: Double = 0.0
private var locationName: String = " "


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)

    apiCall(this)

}    

fun apiCall(@Nullable callback: TravelHistoryInterface?) {

    val apiInterface = ApiInterface.create().getTravelHistory()
    apiInterface.enqueue(
        object : Callback<TravelHistoryListDTO> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<TravelHistoryListDTO>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.i("hithere2", "failure")
                if (callback != null){
                    callback.onError(t);
                }
            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<TravelHistoryListDTO>,
                response: Response<TravelHistoryListDTO>
            ) {
                val travleLocations = response.body()

                if (callback != null){
                    callback.onSuccess(travleLocations);
                }

            }

        }
    )
}

override fun onSuccess(value: TravelHistoryListDTO?) {
    value?.travel_history?.let { calculateDistancePart(it) }
    mTravelLocations= value?.travel_history!!
}

override fun onError(throwable: Throwable) {
    //
}

private fun calculateDistancePart(mmTravel: MutableList<Travel_HistoryDTO>) {
    for (items in mmTravel) {
        val siz: Int = items.latlong.toString().length

        if (items._cn6ca == "15") {
            continue
        }
        for (x in 0 until siz) {
            //trim lat lung
            strList1 = items.latlong.toString().split(',').map { it.trim() }

        }
        if (strList1[0].isEmpty() || strList1[1].isEmpty()) {
            continue
        }

        )

        val thisDistance: Double = DistanceCalculator(
            mylat,
            mylung,
            strList1[0].toDouble(),
            strList1[1].toDouble(),
            "K"
        )
        if (thisDistance < minDistance) {
            Log.i("hahai", thisDistance.toString())
            minDistance = min(minDistance, thisDistance)
            destinationLat = strList1[0].toDouble()
            destinationLong = strList1[1].toDouble()
            locationName = items.address.toString()
        }
    }
}


override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {

    Log.i("bhaiproblem", destinationLat.toString() + " " + destinationLong.toString())
    val sydney = LatLng(destinationLat, destinationLong)
    googleMap?.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title(locationName))
    googleMap?.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 15f))
  }
}
```

//TravelHistoryInterface

```
interface TravelHistoryInterface {
fun onSuccess(@NonNull value: TravelHistoryListDTO?)

fun onError(@NonNull throwable: Throwable)
}
```

Comment: @Fred I followed your suggestion from below post but it didn't work Please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44872115/how-can-i-return-value-from-onresponse-of-retrofit-v2/44881355

Comment: Why are you using @NonNull annotation, kotlin is already null safe out of the box.

Comment: My bad, will remove it. @Animesh

Comment: what are you doing in the nested for loop inside `calculateDistancePart`? Setting strList1 multiple times for no reason?

Comment: actually lat long is a string and not in double format so first I have converted string into double format, 0 index for lat and 1 for long and then used strList1 further

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Animeshz/9165b9dba54aa9677a12651588bbd0c9 line no 6 to 12, you're using only the last element of the list in the if condition

Comment: I still don't think there is any discrepancy in strLlist1, in line no 6, 7 I am iterating over that latlong string to convert it into a list . And in line number 12, I am just making sure that none of the lat or long is empty.

Comment: No, that's the problem and now comes Asynchronous task.

Comment: you are overwriting on the strList1 every time loop runs. it contains only the element from the last iteration of the for loop, at the time of if check

Comment: @Animesh you can also look at my whole code https://github.com/KRN05/Covid_19_2